# how to execute sql select statement in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, select

i have a little problem here:
i have a combobox that gets its values from column in database and i use it to enter data back to another palce in database
like

```
comboBox2.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "DoctorName";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "DoctorCode";
comboBox2.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

this fill the combobox with the name of doctors and the value will be the code of doctor
then

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Clinic\Clinic\Clinc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT   Doctors.DoctorCode, Doctors.DoctorName, SessionReservations.SessionCode, SessionReservations.PatientCode, SessionReservations.ExaminationCode, SessionReservations.DoctorCode AS Expr1, SessionReservations.SessionMonth, SessionReservations.SessionYear   FROM  Doctors INNER JOIN   SessionReservations ON Doctors.DoctorCode = SessionReservations.DoctorCode    WHERE  (Doctors.DoctorCode = @DoctorCode) AND (SessionReservations.SessionMonth = @month) AND (SessionReservations.SessionYear = @year)", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

        try
        {

            da2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DoctorCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue);
            da2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            da2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;

            da2.Fill(ds2);
            cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            con.Close();
}
```

this code is for selecting specific rows and the select statment is working right in sql manager
but while running it gives error that

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at
>   Clinic.DoctorMoneyCall.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Clinic\Clinic\DoctorMoneyCall.cs:line 45"

i just don't understand what's going wrong

Comment: @fenonoga - This is just a null reference problem.  This isn't unique to the running a SQL query.

Comment: try debuging and see if your checkboxes and text box have any value to pass as a parameter

Comment: @MarcGravell line 45 is where it adds the doctor code
da2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DoctorCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to run a select command butt you are adding your parameters to the insert command.

```
        da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DoctorCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue);
        da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: yeah i want select different thing each time, so i have to make variables in the query statment

Comment: but you added them to the Insert command, not the select command.  SQL commands have 4 states: Select, Update, Insert, Delete.  it comes from the SQL querys you can run.  I changed your "insertcommand"'s to "selectCommand"'s

Comment: oh my god thank you very much, i feel stupid actually trying for days to know where the mistake, very stupid thing, i have to be more attention
again thank you

Comment: no prob!  its often something simple.  happened to me recently too.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that one of the objects you used was null. Is the con object correctly initialized?

Comment: yes the connection is working right and i have displayed the values of my textboxes and comboboxes in labels to be sure they working right and they do

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're passing a variable that is null in line 45 of that document. Make sure all values are non-null.

Comment: This doesn't make a great deal of sense.  What he is passing couldn't be `null` since its the contents of a control that exists on the form and both of those values have a default value.